# uwsgi listen queue fills on reload

Tags: django, uwsgi

I'm running a Django app on uwsgi with an average of 110 concurrent users and 5 requests per second during peak hours. I'm finding that when I deploy with `uwsgi reload` during these peak hours I am starting to run into an issue where workers keep getting slowly killed and restarted, and then the uwsgi logs begin to throw an error:

```
Gracefully killing worker 1 (pid: 25145)...
Gracefully killing worker 2 (pid: 25147)...
... a few minutes go by ...
worker 2 killed successfully (pid: 25147)
Respawned uWSGI worker 2 (new pid: 727)
... a few minutes go by ...
worker 2 killed successfully (pid: 727)
Respawned uWSGI worker 2 (new pid: 896)    
... this continues gradually for 25 minutes until:
*** listen queue of socket "127.0.0.1:8001" (fd: 3) full !!! (101/100) ***
```

At this point my app rapidly slows to a crawl and I can only recover with a hard `uwsgi stop` followed by a `uwsgi start`. There are some relevant details which make this situation kind of peculiar:

- This only occurs when I `uwsgi reload`, otherwise the listen queue never fills up on its own
- The error messages and slowdown only start to occur about 25 minutes after the reload
- Even during the moment of crisis, memory and CPU resources on the machine seem fine
- If I deploy during lighter traffic times, this issue does not seem to pop up

I realize that I can increase the listen queue size, but that seems like a band-aid more than an actual solution. And the fact that it only fills up during reload (and takes 25 minutes to do so) leads me to believe that it will fill up eventually regardless of the size. I would like to figure out the mechanism that is *causing* the queue to fill up and address that at the source.

Relevant uwsgi config:

```
[uwsgi]
socket = 127.0.0.1:8001
processes = 4
threads = 2
max-requests = 300
reload-on-rss = 800
vacuum = True
touch-reload = foo/uwsgi/reload.txt
memory-report = true
```

Relevant software version numbers:

```
uwsgi 2.0.14
Ubuntu 14.04.1
Django 1.11.13
Python 2.7.6
```

It appears that our touch reload is not graceful when we have slight traffic, is this to be expected or do we have a more fundamental issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On uwsgi there is a [harakiri](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/FAQ.html#what-is-harakiri-mode) mode that will periodically kill long running processes to prevent unreliable code from hanging (and effectively taking down the app). I would suggest looking there for why your processes are being killed.

As to why a hard stop works and a graceful stop does not -- [it seems to further indicate your application code is hanging](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Management.html#signals-for-controlling-uwsgi). A graceful stop will send `SIGHUP`, which allows resources to be cleaned up in the application. `SIGINT` and `SIGTERM` follow the harsher guidelines of "stop what you are doing right now and exit".

Anyway, it boils down to this not being a `uwsgi` issue, but an issue in your application code. Find what is hanging and why. Since you are not noticing CPU spikes; some probable places to look are...

- blocking connections
- locks
- a long `sleep`

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The key thing you need to look is "listen queue of socket "127.0.0.1:8001" (fd: 3) full !!! (101/100)"

Default listen queue size is 100. Increase the queue size by adding the option "listen" in uwsgi.ini.

"listen = 4096"

Comment: Not to say that I don't believe you, but I personally didn't get this log, although I proved I had the same issue (listen queue was full). See my answer on this question for how I did this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76445286/1151229